# Execute an external command by passing an array, with spaces in filenames

Tags: php, shell, escaping, execute, external-process

I have a PHP script that needs to execute programmes that will work on files that have spaces in the names. Most PHP functions for executing external commands (e.g. `exec()`) take an 1 string argument for the command line to execute. However then you have to do things like `escapeshellarg()` to make your input safe.

Is there some way to execute an external command in PHP with an array. So rather than:

```
exec("ls -l ".escapeshellarg($filename));
```

I can go:

```
exec(array("ls", "-l", $filename));
```

This would mean I don't have to worry about escaping the arguments. I want to avoid using `escapeshellarg()`, since the version I am using has a bug that strips out non-ASCII characters.

Java has this functionality http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29

Comment: I know this is obvious, but for anyone else who comes along: NEVER run external commands based on user input. If the script is not on any web server, fine, but otherwise, make sure you check, double-check, and check 5 more times that there is no way anyone could use this script to perform any command they aren't supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this isn't possible with PHP's builtin functions.

Comment: You still can use the combination of pcntl_fork/pcntl_exec functions. Hovewer in order to obtain a program's output you have to deal with temporary files, since (sounds like) there is no pipe(2) function :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function myExec ( command, arguments )
{
    exec( command + ' ' + implode( ' ', array_map( escapeshellarg, arguments ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I want to avoid using escapeshellarg() (I've updated the question accordingly). The version I'm using has a bug that strips out non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Feel free to replace that function by any other function (define one yourself for example) that filters the characters correctly. I just wanted to give you an idea how to do it :)

Answer (score -1):

Poke's answer is good - however, how many commands do they need to run? I would think about implementing a whitelist of commands and arguments - that way, you can be pretty darn sure they aren't injection malicious input. Something like:

```
$whitelistCommandArray = array('ls' => 'ls', ...);
if (isset($whitelistCommandArray[$userSuppliedCommand]])
{
    //ok its a valid command, lets parse the args next
    ...
}
else echo "Unsupported command";
```

Update/edit:

> Is a whitelist of arguments feasible?
>   What if OP needs to edit a multitude
>   of files? – Matchu

heh I dont know - it could be - totally depends on your needs.

```
$whitelistArray = array('ls' => array('a', 'l', 'h'), ...);
```

Something like that work - with both the command and then an array of arguments for it.

Comment: Is a whitelist of arguments feasible? What if OP needs to edit a multitude of files?

Comment: Yes I do need this script to run on thousands of files that could be named anything and almost certainly will have spaces in their names.